# Is this.fn.apply(this, arguments) redundant?

Tags: javascript

I just came across the following statement in a JavaScript codebase:

```
this.fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

From my understanding of the `apply` function, it's purpose is to change the value of `this`. However, as the same object that the function is attached to is being passed to `apply`, I can't see any difference between this and:

```
this.fn(arguments);
```

Is my understanding correct or is there some difference doing it the first way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apply` takes an array of arguments so:

Given `arguments = [1,2,3]`.

```
this.fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

would give you:

```
this.fn(1,2,3);
```

but:

```
this.fn(arguments);
```

would give you:

```
this.fn( [1,2,3] );
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument in `apply` should be array-like, and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an array-like object with `length`, that array-like object is automatically converted to a set of arguments when passed to `apply`

Here's a quick example

```
var arr = ['val1', 'val2'];

test.apply(null, arr);

function test(arg1, arg2) {
    // arg1 == val1
    // arg2 == val2
}
```

If you called it directly

```
var arr = ['val1', 'val2'];

test(arr);

function test(arg1, arg2) {
    // arg1 == ['val1', 'val2'];
    // arg2 == undefined
}
```

so there's is a difference, when you pass the arguments array directly, it's just passed as the **first** argument to the function, but when passed with `apply()` the array is converted into a set of arguments.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cDbD/)

`call()` on the other hand accepts a set of arguments instead.

```
test.call(this, 'arg1', 'arg2');
```